# About the fact that "almost" all quantum states are entangled

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement

To my understanding, if we randomly choose a vector state from the Hilbert space of a compound quantum system, it will be entangled (i.e. non-factorizable) with probability 1. Now, I know this issue has been discussed a couple of times on this website (like [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9513/how-many-n-qubit-states-are-entangled) for example); but for some academic purpose, I need to cite a reliable source on it. Does anyone know of any book or paper discussing this issue in some detail?

Comment: I don't see a need to cite anything. This is clear to anyone knowing the basics of quantum information. In any case, note that you have to define "randomly".

Comment: @Norbert Schuch: Many thanks for your comment, especially for pointing out the ambiguity in using the term "randomly"! For what I'm doing, I still think I need a reference though.

Comment: What are you doing?! For a paper, you certainly don't need one.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch: Yes, it's a paper, but intended for a philosophy (of science) journal. So I can't presume the readers are familiar with conclusions that would be more or less obvious in quantum physics community.

Comment: How would a reference help them? They presumably wouldn't understand the math. And what philosophical conclusions do you want to draw from that? If you want to talk about nature, states are mixed, and then it is *not* true that the probability that a state is entangled is 1, so you might well draw a conclusion from an invalid starting point. -- I think in the end, if you understand the math and implications of the statement, then you don't need a proof (as it is clear from a dimensional argument, see the answer).

Comment: @Norbert Schuch: Here I'm trying to reformulate an argument (by the philosopher Jonathan Schaffer) that I'm going to criticize later in the paper. The argument depends on this assumption: "[Let us] suppose that there is a wavefunction of the universe. Then it is virtually certain that it will be entangled since measure 1 of all wave-functions are entangled." (Schaffer 2010) Note that although it might be problematic, this is not the assumption I'm going to take issue with.

Comment: But then you can just cite Schaffer who states that. Why do you need an additional reference? (Note that this is problematic in several ways: Taking about the wf of the universe makes no sense, except maybe for god. And it is entirely unclear why it should be random (in any way) - random even in which sense, given there is only one universe which (if it made sense to talk about its wavefunction) were in one state?)

Comment: @Norbert Schuch: If I'm not wrong, elsewhere the author himself recognizes that the talk of the wf of the universe is problematic. But the important point that you (and WillO, in the answer bellow) are making about the need to determine "the distribution we're sampling from" hasn't been noticed, I think. About your last question, I think the randomness involved is only epistemological; that is, roughly speaking, the claim is sth like: for all we know, the wf of the universe belongs to a space in which a random state is most likely entangled.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch: Oh, and I'm trying to motivate their argument as far as I can, before criticizing it. That's why I'm looking for a reference other than Schaffer himself, which makes this point more accurately.

Comment: Regarding the randomness: For any "reasonable" type of randomness the statement is true. (Of course, "reasonable" depends on the situation, but basically it is the same as saying that if I randomly pick a point in a square, it will have probability zero to be at the boundary, or at some line through the square.) -- Regarding the reference/criticism: Since you won't criticise the probability 1 point (I hope, since it is mathematically true), why don't you simply acknowledge its truth based o Schaffer's claim?

Comment: @Norbert Schuch: [Sorry for this delayed response, and thanks for another helpful comment!] Yes, I think you're right and citing Schaffer himself on this point would be my last resort. (it requires a little bit of restructuring; in the current draft I've tried not to cite philosophers in the section introducing quantum entanglement, before grappling with what some of them take to be its implications. Now, this issue of ubiquity of entanglement is currently part of that very introduction. Sorry for going into irrelevant details here! :))

Answer (score 3):

> if we randomly choose a vector state from the Hilbert space of a compound quantum system, it will be entangled (i.e. non-factorizable) with probability 1

This is either true or false, depending on what distribution you're sampling from.

What **is** true is that the entangled states form a dense open subset  of the full state space, which gives a very strong sense in which almost all states are entangled.

If you think of two particles with $n$ and $m$ dimensional state spaces, then the tensor product has dimension $nm$ while the unentangled states are an image of the direct product (of dimension $n+m$), so (except in trivial cases) the unentangled states have positive codimension, which is even stronger than saying the entangled states are dense.

Comment: To be fair, this does not answer the question.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch:  The paper asks for a reference to support a false statement.  I think the best answer one can give in this situation is to point out that the statement is false, so there will be no reliable references to it.  And it might be additionally helpful to mention a related statement that is true, but so easy to verify that a reference would be superfluous.

Comment: Fair enough; I was just saying that this was not what the question asked for. Probably would have been more of a comment. Also, while it does indeed depend on the notion of randomness, it does not for any non-singular measure.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch :  Fair enough!  :)

Comment: @WillO: It was a very helpful answer. Thanks! I'm unfamiliar with some concepts (like codimension, etc.) tbh. That's part of the reason (but not all of it) that it would be much better if I could find the similar discussion in a textbook or sth.

Comment: Sorry I don't get the co-dimensionality argument: if $n=2$ and $m=3$, then all states of the type 
$\vert \psi_i\rangle\vert\phi_j\rangle$ are surely separable ($i=1,2$, $j=1,2,3$), and there are $6$ of them.  Indeed the product states (all separable) form a basis for the tensor product space.

Comment: @Zerothehero:  Every unentangled state has the form $\phi\otimes\psi$.  There are $n$ dimensions worth of choices for $\phi$ and $m$ for $\psi$.

Comment: @WillO You mean every *unentangled* state?... but there are still $m\times n$ of them.  Maybe I need to think this through a little more...

Comment: @zerothehero:  Yes, i meant unentangled---edited to fix, thanks.  You wrote down 6 states, but they lie in a subspace (NOT a sub-vector space) of dimension 5.

Comment: I guess that's the part I don't see (at least not at this point in my day...)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero:  I totally get the "can't see it at this point in my day" phenomenon.  But (I'll do this over ${\mathbb R}$):  The dimension of $X= {\mathbb R}^2\times{\mathbb R}^3$ is 5.  The dimension of $Y={\mathbb R}^2\otimes{\mathbb R}^3$ is 6.  Map $X$ to $Y$ by taking $(\phi,\psi)$ to $\phi\otimes\psi$.  This is a (nonlinear) map from a 5-dimensional space to the 6-dimensional space of all states.  The image of that map (which cannot be more than 5-dimensional) is precisely the subspace (again, topologically; it's not a vector subspace) of unentangled states.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero:  You have identified six linearly independent elements of that subspace, but because it's not a vector subspace it does not include all of their linear combinations.  In fact it can't, because it's not more than 5-dimensional.

Comment: Don't you need $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ somewhere?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero:  Thanks again for the correction.  I managed to edit in time.  (I re-edited the $\oplus$ back to $\times$ because this seems to me to be the more natural way to think of it, but of course in this case they are the same thing.)

Comment: @WillO I actually have to work  :( but I'll come back to this later (probably tomorrow).  I may ping you again and we'll start a separate chat if need be.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero You don't need to think about co-dimensions - just think about how many real parameters are needed to specify a state $|\phi\rangle\otimes|\psi\rangle$ vs. a general state. Smaller number of parameters => probability zero (more or less).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch yes this is how I would think about this...but I kinda curious about the co-dimension argument.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Well, the map from the coefficients to the state is nice (a tensor product, so quadratic), which means that the parameters of phi and psi parametrize some nice manifold. This manifold has some dimension which is smaller than the dimension of the full space (just as for a linear subspace). The codimension is the difference of the two. In the end it is just a way of putting the counting argument (+the "niceness" of the map) into fancy words.